# HIVE - Group by more than one column and Sum

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, sum

I can't figure how to write this in HIVE correctly, any tips?

[image: sample table]

Here's my code that doesn't work.

```
(Create table  new as
             SELECT num_visits,  entry, month, year, clinic , city
sum (num_visit, entry)  
    Group by  num_visits,  entry, month, year, clinic , city
       FROM  old    
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the logic you want is:

```
select 
    sum(num_visits), 
    sum(entry), 
    month, 
    year, 
    clinic, 
    city
from old
group by month, year, clinic, city
```

This groups together rows that have the same `(month, year, clinic, city)`, while summing `num_visit` and `entry`.